# Can I mock a protected superclass method call in Java?

Tags: java, mocking, protected, super, superclass

I have stumbled upon a testing problem of mocking a call of protected method from a super class.

e.g. :

```
public class A extends B {
    @Override
    protected int calculate(int x, int y) {
         int result = super.calculate(x, y);
         result += 10;
         return result;
    } 
}
```

So is it possible by any means to mock `super.calcluate(x,y)`? I have tried it with spy but spy could not invoke super method cause it's out of scope I think.

Answer (score 3):

I would imagine a mocking framework would allow for you to mock `protected` members, but if your mocking framework doesn't, have you considered creating a stub of the class?

```
public class AStub extends A {
    @Override
    protected int calculate(int x, int y) {
        // do stub calculation 
        return calculation;
    }
}
```

Comment: How does this help? It sounds like the OP wants to insert a mock method between `A::calculate()` and `B::calculate()` so that the former calls the mock method instead of the inherited method from `B`. Overriding `A::calculate()` bypasses both methods entirely. That being said, the original need seems like a code smell to me. Perhaps `A` should compose `B` instead of extend it.

Answer (score 3):

When you mock an object, you don't care about its implementation. You only add expectations about which method is called.

If you mock A, then your expectations will say something "I expect method calculate on A to be called with parameters 2 and 3, and the result will be 15".

You don't care what the calculate method does in practice, that's the whole point of mocking.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't be mocking a call to super. A unit test is intended to test the functionality of a class, and the functionality of ancestor classes **is a part of that functionality**.

The only time you should need to mock a super class is when the ancestor class behaves badly - such as initializing outside classes as part of its own initialization (without the projection of dependency injection) or accessing external resources (without the projection of dependency injection). If you have access to the ancestor class, refactor it to remove these problems.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, I don't think there's an easy way to mock `super.calculate`.

I can see that you want to write a "clean" unit test for A that does not rely on B, which is a reasonable aim. But if A is calling a protected method on its superclass, Java makes it hard to decouple the two classes.

This is one of many examples where using inheritance couples classes more closely than you'd like.

Ideally A would *wrap* B rather than extending it (i.e. using composition rather than inheritance), and would then call `myB.calculate` rather than `super.calculate`.

Both classes could implement the same interface (e.g. Calculable) to allow them to be treated polymorphically by clients. This approach would requre B.calculate to be public, or at least package-public. Your unit test could set up an A that wraps a mock B, thereby solving your problem.

I think you have to choose between increasing the visibility of calculate(), as described above, and writing a clean unit test - I don't think you can have both.

Comment: Yes, I think this is one of those times I would test `A` and `B` as a single unit, especially if `A` is abstract. Many people would tell you to avoid testing/mocking protected methods directly as they depend on the implementation details, but I often do so since the unit test should be exercising those details. I think it comes down to how clean of a separation you have, but if it's that clean you should probably use composition instead, as you say.